# Knowing a 12 word seed phrase is there a way to find which derivation path has a positive ETH balance

Tags: metamask, recovery, bip39, bip32, trustwallet

I have the seed phrase.
I used it with different wallets at the same time.

- Chromia Metamask
- Firefox Metamask
- Chrome Metamask
- Metamask Mobile
- Trustwallet Mobile

Seed phrase was also used to create multicoin wallet in Trustwallet.
I was under influence of mind altering substances.
Funds have not left my wallet but the last transaction shows that I allowed for a new token to be traded.
Day after, entering seed phrase both in metamask and trust wallet gives empty wallets in result.

Long story short: while having a seed phrase is there a way to determine which of the possible derivation path generated out of this phrase has been used and or have a positive ETH balance?

Funds are left untouched since january.

Answer (score 0):

Without coding, you can try the offline, standalone version of

https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/releases

The check each address using an explorer to see which has a balance.

**Always be very careful where you enter your seed phrase.**

Good luck.